# Connect Android to localhost?

Tags: android, xampp

I want to open a website on my android phone with `localhost` website as they are connected to same router.
On my Desktop `localhost:8100` is the address of my webpage.
On my android phone when I enter the `IP address` of my desktop it opens `192.168.31.194/dashboard/`  . `192.168.31.194` is my IP.
But if I try `192.168.31.194:8100` nothing happens.

Comment: localhost:8100 is not that address to your website.  I am willing to bet it is localhost:8100/index.html or some other filename.fileextension you are using.  Add this to file and extension to what you type on your phone and it should open if on the same network

Comment: first try to open your webpage in your browser if it is open then try to open it in android.